# How to take Product attribute value and pass in JS?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I want to get attribute value which is date and wants to pass it into JS file, I have my JS files linked up properly, basically I am displaying timer in product detail page and I want to display timer based on dynamic attribute value.

I am very new to magento 2 and I don't know where to start:

I am using this in my hello.phtml

```
<?php
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
?>
<div data-mage-init='{"hello": {"message": "HELLO WORLD!"}}' id="testdiv">
    Content
</div>
```

My hello.js

```
define([
        "jquery"
    ], function($){
        "use strict";
        return function(config, element) {
            console.log("Asd");
            var deadline = new Date("Apr 15, 2020 15:37:25").getTime();
            var x = setInterval(function() {
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                var t = deadline - now;
                var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = days + "d "
                    + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                if (t < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                }
            }, 1000);
            //document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML="newtext";
            //alert("test");
        }
    }
)
```

Can anyone help me out, from where I can get attribute value and pass it to JS.

Comment: are you getting HELLO WORLD! in your JS ?

Comment: Yup I do get it

Comment: OK if you are getting static value, you can use `<div data-mage-init='{"hello": {"message": "<?= $attribute->getFrontendLabel(); ?>"}}' id="testdiv">
    Content
</div>` for attribute value.

Comment: can u give me an example I am not getting $attribute as well

Comment: first cross check you are getting value of `$attribute` in phtml.

Comment: where is the code for getting `$_product` ?

Comment: Hi @Pawan I dnt know where to write and how I am new to magento 2 can u help me out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106426/discussion-between-pawan-and-jaymin).